# How to increase/decrease all integers in the same line in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, `ctrl+a` is to increase an integer and `ctrl+x` is to decrease an integer.

For example, to modify the following code to append 1, 2, 3 to the array, I can simply put `ctrl+a` once in line3 and twice in line4:

```
array = []      # line1
array.append(1) # line2
array.append(1) # line3
array.append(1) # line4
```

Then it will becomes:

```
array = []      # line1
array.append(1) # line2
array.append(2) # line3
array.append(3) # line4
```

But it's not convenient while I want to increase more than one integer in a line. For example, I want to change:

```
rank1 = 1
rank1 = 1
rank1 = 1
```

to:

```
rank1 = 1
rank2 = 2
rank3 = 3
```

My question is, is it a convenient way to increase all the integer in the same line via one keystroke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first type the following two lines:

```
array = []
rank1 = 1
```

Then put you cursor in line 2. Then type the following by order:

```
qa
yy
p
shift+v
:
s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)+1/g
q
5@a
```

And here '5' can change to how many repeat you want.

Ok, this works, but it becomes more complicated.

Comment: This only increments the first number in the line. The question is asking about how to increment **all** numbers in the line.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not what I'm asking. But still thank you for teaching this recording skill.

Answer (score 3):

In Vim version 8 (which didn't exist when this question was first asked) you can use `g Ctrl+A` to increase a column of numbers by 1 more each time. So starting with the above example of:

```
rank1 = 1
rank1 = 1
rank1 = 1
rank1 = 1
rank1 = 1
```

Move to the second line and press `V` to visually highlight it. Move to the last line, then type `g Ctrl+A`. That increases the first 1 (on the second line) to 2, the one on the line after to 3, and so on, giving you:

```
rank1 = 1
rank2 = 1
rank3 = 1
rank4 = 1
rank5 = 1
```

To then increase the column of 1s at the end of the lines, you need to select a block which doesn't include the numbers earlier on the line. For instance, with the cursor still on the second line, type `$ Ctrl+V 3j`. Then do `g Ctrl+A` again, and you get:

```
rank1 = 1
rank2 = 2
rank3 = 3
rank4 = 4
rank5 = 5
```

That still involves doing each number on a line separately, but because it does all lines at once, it only involves doing it twice in total, so should still be quicker.

Answer (score 2):

This command should do it:

```
:s/\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 1/g
```

Edit: "+" should be escaped in Vim